# google map reverse geocoding working on my main domain but not working at my subdomain

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am working google map of my website using google map API, my domain name is http://99mntra.com and sub-domain is http://m.99mntra.com, but problem is GEO location is working on my main domain http://99mntra.com, but on my sub-domain http://m.99mntra.com is not working GEO location API, both code is same and its key is different. I am try many times but I am not getting any result so please resolve my issue sir. where is problem can i fix it by your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your google API console. I had a similar situation when I had set "allowed domain" for a certain key to be my root domain only.